# Binding animation on many elements

Tags: jquery

I try to do some kind of grid that need to show dot based animation in the future.
But it seams to perform pretty slowly even with a few elements (i need to apply it to maybe 5times that many items)

```
$('div').bind('shrink', function(){
       var $that = $(this).find('> em > span');
       $that.animate({'width': '3px', 'height': '3px'}, 500);
    }).bind('grow', function(){
       var $that = $(this).find('> em > span');
       $that.delay(50).animate({'width': '100%', 'height': '100%'}, 300);
    }).append('<em><span><span><em/>');
//triggering shrink and grow on hover
```

before starting to do complex animations i wanted to test it with a hover effect.

you can take a look at the demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/meo/GvfVb/7/

How could i improve the performance of this script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to get some performance improvements with this version:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/GvfVb/10/

```
var shrink = function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'width': '3px',
        'height': '3px'
    }, 500);
};
var grow = function() {
    $(this.firstChild.firstChild)
        .delay(50).animate({
        'width': '20px',
        'height': '20px'
    }, 300);
};

$('div').append('<em><span><span><em/>')
    .find('> em > span').mouseenter( shrink )
    .end().mouseleave(grow)
    .click(function() {
        $(this).unbind('mouseleave', grow);
});
```

Here are the changes I made:

- Changed `shrink` and `grow` into named functions, so that `.trigger()` doesn't need to be called to fire them, while retaining the ability to remove them by name.
- Placed the `mouseenter` event directly on the `<span>` tag so you don't need to do a `.find()` every time `mouseenter` fires.
- The `mouseleave` needs to be on the `<div>` so I optimized it by removing the `.find()` and replacing it with a native `this.firstChild.firstChild`.
- This was probably the biggest performance improvement: I changed the `grow` function to animate the `width` to an absolute value of `20px` instead of `100%`. Things really smoothed out with that change.

You could also probably unbind the `mouseleave` when you click so that it isn't firing to no effect after the `mouseenter` has been unbound.

Comment: all you comments make total sense to me. Thank you. But its still pretty slow :/ I was binding the functions as events on the elements. So i could easily trigger them from an external function, that would actually draw the pictures on the dot frame. Unless someone post the WONDER SOLUTION to my problem, i give you the right awnser +1 for your effort and your explicit comments.

Comment: @meo - Sorry I couldn't help more. It may help a bit to move to an entirely native javascript solution instead of jQuery. Not sure though.

Comment: im not sure if am able to optimize the animation event more then they already are in jQuery

Comment: i playd around with it. And its even faster if you use EM as sizes for the dots and just animate the fontsize.

Comment: @meo - Interesting. I wonder why that's quicker. Good to know anyway.

Comment: you can check it out here: http://meodai.ch/puenktli/ the function is not ideal yet, but im working on it. I gona replace the JS animate by a CSS3 transition to see how big the speed difference is.